# How to achieve layered line art effect?

Tags: line-art

Wondering if there is an easy way to achieve a layered line effect as seen here:

[image]
[image]

Or does this have to be manually drawn using the pen tool?  Essentially I'm wondering if there is a tool in illustrator that allows you to repeat the pattern.
Thanks!

Comment: Object -> Path -> Offset will help

Comment: ermm.. what software?

Comment: Read: "Essentially I'm wondering if there is a tool in illustrator that allows you to repeat the pattern."

Answer (score 6):

Step 1: Draw a few strait lines as shown in the image. Select them all and create a artbrush. No settings need to be changed.

Step 2: Draw your circles. Keep in mind that they need to touch each other. Select the two circles and choose the newly created artbrush from the brushpanel.

Step 3: Keep the 2 circles selected and expand them (Object > Expand). Now you can delete the parts that you want to be behind.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use **Adobe Illustrator**

Draw a series of lines. Make them an **Art Brush**. Apply the brush to paths.
Expand, edit and color.

[image: art brush]